# checkbox bindnig to bool causes application is in break mode

Tags: wpf, checkbox

Fragment of my wpf

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="abonamenty_grid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nabywca" Binding="{Binding nabywca}" Width="200" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Odbiorca" Binding="{Binding odbiorca}" Width="200" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Asortyment" Binding="{Binding czas_umowy_w_miesiącach}" Width="100" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kwota" Binding="{Binding kwota_abonamentu}" Width="*" />
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Faktura auto" Binding="{Binding wystawiaj_automatycznie_fakturę}" Width="30" />
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Fa auto na początku miesiąca" Binding="{Binding czy_fa_auto_na_początku_okresu}" Width="30" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Fragment of my query

```
                     select new
                     {
                         abonament_id = myabonamenty.id_abonament,
                         asortyment = nexotowary.Nazwa,
                         nabywca = nexonabywcy.NazwaSkrocona,
                         odbiorca = nexoodbiorcy.NazwaSkrocona,
                         wystawiaj_automatycznie_fakturę = myabonamenty.wystawiaj_automatycznie_fakturę,
                         czy_fa_auto_na_początku_okresu = myabonamenty.czy_fa_auto_na_początku_okresu,
                         kwota_abonamentu = myabonamenty.kwota_abonamentu
                     }).ToList();
```

TextColumn  binding works but CheckBoxColumn binding. When displaing page with CheckBox binding application goes in break mode ( I have a window application is in break mode ).
wystawiaj_automatycznie_fakturę,czy_fa_auto_na_początku_okresu are bool.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You are using a dynamic List to bind. Can you confirm, with the debugger, that wystawiaj_automatycznie_fakturę and czy_fa_auto_na_początku_okresu are both boolean values (and not null)?

Comment: Try using `TargetNullValue` on your combo box `Binding` and put False or True depending on what you want to test.

Comment: I don't get any error. My application stops and displaing : application i s in break mode . When I continue my application ends. I'm sure that wystawiaj_automatycznie_fakturę and czy_fa_auto_na_początku_okresu are both boolean values (and not null).

Comment: If your columns aren't boolean values, you won't get an error until you try to bind (because of your dynamic type). What are the types of myabonamenty.wystawiaj_automatycznie_fakturę and myabonamenty.czy_fa_auto_na_początku_okresu?

Comment: They are both bool . I'm reciveing also error when I'm using only one of them. From arAbonamenty.cs:
        public bool wystawiaj_automatycznie_fakturę { get; set; }
        public bool czy_fa_auto_na_początku_okresu { get; set; }

Comment: In the xaml you provided there is not binding to the DataGrid.ItemsSource, which means you set the ItemsSource in the code behind (where you may be doing something incorrectly). Refactor your code, so that you have a property of type ObservableCollection<arAbonamenty>() in your DataContext and bind it  to DataGrid.ItemsSource.

Comment: I found a solution, creating new class myabo with items from select and changing select new {...}  to select new myabo solved this problem

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer to this problem is creating myabo class:

```
    private class myabo
    {
        public int abonament_id { get; set; }
        public string asortyment { get; set; }
        public string nabywca { get; set; }
        public string odbiorca { get; set; }
        public bool automatyczna_faktura { get; set; }
        public bool? czy_fa_auto_na_początku_okresu { get; set; }
        public decimal kwota_abonamentu { get; set; }
    }
```

and changing select:

```
        var query = (from myabonamenty in myNexo_ARWALEntities.ArAbonamenty
                     join nexotowary in myNexo_ARWALEntities.Asortymenty
                     on myabonamenty.nexo_towar equals nexotowary.Id
                     join myklienci in myNexo_ARWALEntities.ArKlienci
                     on myabonamenty.id_klient equals myklienci.id_klient
                     where (grupa_tw == null || (grupa_tw != null && nexotowary.Grupa_Id > 0))
                     where (kiedy_fakturować == null || myabonamenty.czy_fa_auto_na_początku_okresu == kiedy_fakturować)
                     join nexoodbiorcy in myNexo_ARWALEntities.Podmioty
                     on myklienci.Nexo_klient_odbiorca equals nexoodbiorcy.Id into nexoodbiorcyg
                     from nexoodbiorcy in nexoodbiorcyg.DefaultIfEmpty()

                     join nexonabywcy in myNexo_ARWALEntities.Podmioty
                     on myklienci.Nexo_klient_nabywca equals nexonabywcy.Id into nexonabywcyg
                     from nexonabywcy in nexonabywcyg.DefaultIfEmpty()

                     select new myabo
                     {
                         abonament_id = myabonamenty.id_abonament,
                         asortyment = nexotowary.Nazwa,
                         nabywca = nexonabywcy.NazwaSkrocona,
                         odbiorca = nexoodbiorcy.NazwaSkrocona,
                         automatyczna_faktura=myabonamenty.wystawiaj_automatycznie_fakturę,
                         czy_fa_auto_na_początku_okresu = myabonamenty.czy_fa_auto_na_początku_okresu,
                         kwota_abonamentu = myabonamenty.kwota_abonamentu
                     }).ToList();

        abonamenty_grid.ItemsSource = query;
```